# Chain of direct summands and idempotents

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, idempotents

Let $M_R$ be a module and $A_1\supseteq A_2\supseteq...$ a chain of direct summands of $M$. I want to find a set of nonzero idempotents $f_i\in End(M)$ with $f_if_j=0$ whenever $i\neq j$.

I know that there are idempotents $f_i\in End(M)$ such that $f_i(M)=A_i$. But I think these are in general not orthgonal. I guess I have to modify my chain, but I don't know how. Any hints?

Comment: If you admit an idempotent to be zero, an obvious answer would be $f_i = 0$.

Comment: If $p_i$ is the projection onto $A_i$, try $f_i = p_{i-1} (1-p_i)$, $f_1 = 1-p_1$. This should be the projection onto $A_{i-1} / A_i$, the complementary summand of $A_i$ in $A_{i-1}$.

Comment: Thanks! I am still struggling with the solution: I can show that with this definition $f_if_j=0$ if $i<j$, but I can not show $f_jf_i=0$ and I also have difficulties with seeing that $f_i$ is an idempotent. It seems like I need something like $p_ip_{i-1}=p_i$ which I don't see...

Comment: I'm pretty sure $p_i p_{i-1} = p_i$. If $M \ni m = (a_i + a'_i) + b$ where $a_i \in A_i$, $a'_i$ is in the complementary summand to $A_i$ in $A_{i-1}$, and $b$ is in the complementary summand to $A'_{i-1}$ in $M$, then $p_i p_{i-1}(m) = p_i(a_i+a'_i) = a_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that (for the $f_i$ you found) $f_if_j=f_jf_i=f_j$ whenever $j\geq i$.

With that in mind, look at $\{f_i-f_{i+1}\mid i\in \mathbb N\}$.

Comment: You can either interpret $0$ as being in $\mathbb N$ or not. You could throw in $f_0=1$ if you do include $0$ :)

Comment: This is very clear! Good answer. Not to take away anything, but I would like to note that it is equivalent to (but much clearer than) my comment above (modulo a shift by $1$ in indices).

Comment: @ZachTeitlerYep, they are ultimately the same.  One could hardly come to a different answer, given the hypotheses :)